# JLabel image from byte[]

Tags: java, swing

**I have an image stored in oracle DB as byte[].**

```
private void uploadPhoto(EntityManager em){
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal=fc.showOpenDialog(Shop.this);
    File selected=fc.getSelectedFile();
    if(returnVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            System.out.println(selected);
            img = ImageIO.read(selected);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Image bufferedImage =img.getScaledInstance(lbluserPicture.getWidth(), lbluserPicture.getHeight(),
                Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        lbluserPicture.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bufferedImage));
        /*
         * ------------------Storing the image in the DB---------------------
         */
        WritableRaster raster= img.getRaster();
         DataBufferByte data=(DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
        activeUserShop.setImage(data.getData());
        System.out.println("Image uploaded! Lenght: "+data.getData().length+"bytes");
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        System.out.println(activeUserShop.toString());
        tx.begin();
        manager.updateUser(activeUserShop);
        tx.commit();
    }
```

That works.

**Then I have to take out the image and set it as an imageIcon on a Jlabel**

```
private void placeMyImage(User u) {
        try {
            byte[] imageObtained=manager.findByUserName(u).getImage();
            lbluserPicture.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageObtained));
            System.out.println(imageObtained.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            lbluserPicture.setIcon(placeDefaultImage(defaultUserImageURL));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

But that last code doesn't seem to work.The byte[].lenght is the exact same length as the image that is imported in the DB.No e.stacktrace 
printed.The label doesn't change.**What do I do ?**

Comment: Have you even tried basic debugging? See if the byte[] you get actually has the right image, see if the label is updating.

Comment: Use ImageIO.write to write the image data to a ByteArrayOutputStream, for this, you can get the byte[] and send this to your entity. When you want to read it, wrap the byte[] in a ByteArrayInputStream and use ImageIO.read to read it

Comment: byte[] imageObtained=manager.findByUserName(u).getImage(); 
 System.out.println(imageObtained.length); it gets the right image.
The label is updated because otherwise its has the default Image

Comment: You are, essentially, writing the "pixel" raw data to the database, when you should be writing the actual image in a readable format (like png or jpg)

Comment: In the college they make us study all kinds of wrong stuff.Thats why I usualy ask here.Thanks.

Comment: "As a byte[]" - consider: in what format? A byte array is nothing to do with an image; you're converting it in a particular way, and this particular way doesn't save the size of the image.

Comment: (ImageIO handles common file formats like PNG, JPEG, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you are writing the raw "pixel" data to the databse, this isn't very helpful and while I'm sure there's probably away to reconstitute this data back into something that might be useful, it's all just a lot of work which can done more easily...

So first, use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write the image to

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);

byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray()
activeUserShop.setImage(bytes);
System.out.println("Image uploaded! Lenght: "+bytes+"bytes");
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
System.out.println(activeUserShop.toString());
tx.begin();
manager.updateUser(activeUserShop);
tx.commit();
```

Then simply use a `ByteArrayInputStream` to read the image again

```
byte[] imageObtained=manager.findByUserName(u).getImage();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageObtained);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(bais);
```

I should point out that this is only going to work with "relatively" small images due to the limitations arrays and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and unless you can write directly to an `OutputStream` and read directly from an `InputStream`, you'll have to live with this limitation. This may not be an issue, but you should be aware of it ;)